# Output code with english characters instead of non-english in lstlisting latex?

Tags: latex, non-english, lstlisting

i wanna insert an ansys apdl code code text in my thesis.
I have tried the \begin{lstlisting} for my code **(english)** since i have tha package.
My thesis template is put to have **greek** as default language so when i compile the lstlisting in latex i get this output
[latex output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U95eD.png)  (greek characters).
I have tried use \eng{} inside or outside of the \begin{lstlisting} but i get greek characters either way.
this the code :

```
\begin{lstlisting}
/AUX15  
/UNITS,SI 
IOPTN,IGES,SMOOTH   
IOPTN,MERGE,YES 
IOPTN,SOLID,YES 
IOPTN,SMALL,YES 
IOPTN,GTOLER, DEFA  
IGESIN,'.arc_nosup_2','igs',' '  
! APLOT   
!*  
FINISH 
\end{lstlisting}
```

Anyone has any idea how can i get an ouput of this code with english characters instead of greek?

a minimal example is like that :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[unicode,linktocpage,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{breakurl}

% >> Math package:
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{parskip}

% improved layout of figure captions with extra margin, smaller font than text
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,textfont = it]{caption}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{babel,varioref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage{url}
% \usepackage{multibib}

\usepackage{caption}

% TABLE OF CONTENTS PACKAGES
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

% Line Spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

% fancy header
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
%\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

% footnotes: waring in case of splitted footnote
\usepackage{fnbreak}

% extra controlabity for enumerators
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Section headings format
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{sectsty}

% appendix
\usepackage{appendix}


\begin{lstlisting}
/AUX15  
/UNITS,SI 
IOPTN,IGES,SMOOTH   
IOPTN,MERGE,YES 
IOPTN,SOLID,YES 
IOPTN,SMALL,YES 
IOPTN,GTOLER, DEFA  
IGESIN,'.arc_nosup_2','igs',' '  
! APLOT   
!*  
FINISH
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: i did the minimal example you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\selectlanguage{english}` to temporarily switch to English:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[unicode,linktocpage,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{breakurl}

% >> Math package:
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{parskip}

% improved layout of figure captions with extra margin, smaller font than text
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,textfont = it]{caption}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{babel,varioref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage{url}
% \usepackage{multibib}

\usepackage{caption}

% TABLE OF CONTENTS PACKAGES
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

% Line Spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

% fancy header
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
%\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

% footnotes: waring in case of splitted footnote
\usepackage{fnbreak}

% extra controlabity for enumerators
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Section headings format
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{sectsty}

% appendix
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}

Greek

{
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{lstlisting}
/AUX15  
/UNITS,SI 
IOPTN,IGES,SMOOTH   
IOPTN,MERGE,YES 
IOPTN,SOLID,YES 
IOPTN,SMALL,YES 
IOPTN,GTOLER, DEFA  
IGESIN,'.arc_nosup_2','igs',' '  
! APLOT   
!*  
FINISH
\end{lstlisting}
}

Greek

\end{document}
```